# Making new Numpy array with indexes of another Numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, element

I have an 10 x N array as follows:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  1.]]
```

I want a Numpy array of the following 1 x N format, where each element in the new array is the value of the index filled with '1' in the 10 x N array.

For example, the process would convert the above into the array:

```
[[ 1.  7.  0. ...,  7,  9.  9.]]
```

I have had some success with using the function:

```
np.where(array > 0)[0][0]
```

This gives me a value for my final array but my attempts to fill the array in the required format have not worked. Furthermore, my implementations have not been very pythonic. Is there a pythonic solution to the above question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

You only care about the *column*, since your second array is 1D, right now you are grabbing the *row* from `numpy.where`

If you can guarantee that there is only one `1` per row, just grab the columns from the output of `numpy.where`:

```
np.where(a==1)[1]
```

```
array([5, 0, 2, 4, 2, 6], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :D